# Format date string in Material-UI TableCell

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, material-ui

I have this Material-UI `TableCell` where `item.created_at` is a date string in the format `2019-03-25T19:09:21Z`:

```
<TableCell align="left">{item.created_at}</TableCell>
```

I'd like to change this to a more reader friendly format that only contains the date. I'd be happy with either `25/03/2019` or `25th Mar 2019`.

I've tried this without success:

```
<TableCell align="left" type="date">{item.created_at}</TableCell>
```

How is this done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use [MomentJS](https://momentjs.com/docs/) you can format like this (You should use it it's a very good helper with dates)

```
moment('2019-03-25 15:30:00').format('D MMMM YYYY'); //Displays 25th Mar 2019
moment('2019-03-25 15:30:00').format('D/MM/YYYY');   //Displays 25/03/2019
```

Then use it like this

```
<TableCell align="left" type="date">{moment(item.created_at).format('D/MM/YYYY')}</TableCell>
```