# Format Date in MUI DataGrid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

How can i format the date data in MUI DataGrid from mongo format to moment.

Also I want to include an extra field with the  edit icon which when clicked, would redirect to the edit page

Here's what i have.

```
 const columns = [

    { field: 'createdAt', headerName: 'Join Date', width: 100 },
    { field: *****, headerName: 'Edit', width: 120 }
]
```

I get my output as `2022-04-03T09:24:40.199Z`. I want to format it using moment.js. how can i achieve this?

Is there a way of including the edit icon and passing the id of the clicked item

Since the field contains the data from the database represented by a string. I have tried template literals. It didn't work as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Format date string in Material-UI TableCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56231857/format-date-string-in-material-ui-tablecell)

Answer (score 14):

Try adding `valueFormatter` property into createdAt field object as shown in the code below. This should solve your problem.

```
const columns = [
   ...

   { 
     field: 'createdAt', 
     headerName: 'Join Date', 
     width: 100,
     valueFormatter: params => 
     moment(params?.value).format("DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm A"),
   },

   ...
]
```

You can also find more about DataGrid cell customization in this document:

https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/column-definition/#rendering-cells

Comment: i don't have moment in my project. Worked for me in this way: ``valueFormatter: params => new Date(params?.value).toLocaleString()``, is this ok?. Thanks for your answer, +1

Comment: Yes, it is definitely fine. You can use any function or library as long as its return type is string.

Answer (score 3):

For lightweight `dayjs` you can adopt Be Munin's answer like

```
const columns = [
   ...

   { 
     field: 'createdAt', 
     headerName: 'Join Date', 
     width: 100,
     valueFormatter: (params) => dayjs(params.value).format('DD/MM/YYYY'),
   },

   ...
]
```

Comment: I am using Mui v5 for DataGrid. Its working fine for me.